# Calculate FPS in opengl game for iphone ( EAGLView )

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, eaglview

I used the apple's crash landing example as base to program some small games for iphone. Now i would like to meassure the frames per second in my games.

I'm curious about how can I calculate the FPS per second, can anyone help me to understand or point me to any way to do It ?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the time the last frame took to draw in milliseconds, the rest is easy: `1.0f/deltaTime`